# Instaling without cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift

https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-SMTP

Im sorry if this is a dumb question but I am trying to install this inside my app and there is no documentation on how to add it. I always use cocoapods but it seems this can't be used for this project. Could anyone help me I need this functionality

Answer (score 0):

That particular project/repo uses [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/), so in Terminal cd into the project root:

```
$ swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

This will create an `.xcodeproject` which you'll then open and build. Once you've done that just drag the built framework into the project you'd like to include it in and use the import:

```
import SwiftSMTP
```

Comment: I may need pictures because this is new to me

Comment: nvm I figured it out

Comment: missing required module 'CommonCrypto'?

Comment: @BoJackson: CommonCrypto errors would be something not related to this question.